# Django-how to set only one review per user and movie

Tags: html, django

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Play(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
plot = models.TextField(max_length=900)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)
cast = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICE, max_length=10)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='movie')
year = models.DateTimeField()
author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
return self.title

class Review(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
movie = models.ForeignKey(Play, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
text = models.TextField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from .models import Play, Review
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def movies_list(request):
article = Play.objects.all().order_by('year')
return render(request, "articles/movies_list.html", {"articles":article})
def movies_detail(request, slug):
articles = Play.objects.get(slug=slug)
all_reviews = Review.objects.all().order_by('movie')
isReviewAllowed = check_user_review(request, slug)
return render(request, "articles/movies_detail.html", {"articles":articles,'all_reviews': all_reviews, 'isReviewAllowed': isReviewAllowed})

@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def article_create(request):
if request.method == "POST":
form = forms.CreatePlay(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.author = request.user
instance.save()
return redirect("movies:home")
else:
form = forms.CreatePlay()
return render(request, "articles/article_create.html", {"form":form})
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def sub_review(request, slug):
 form = forms.CreateReview(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.user = request.user
show = Play.objects.get(slug=slug)
instance.movie = show
instance.save()
return redirect("movies:detail", slug=slug)
 else:
form = forms.CreateReview()
return render(request, "articles/review.html", {"form":form, "slug":slug})
def check_user_review(request, slug):
check = Review.objects.values_list('user', 'movie')
 test = Review.objects.count()
watch = Play.objects.get(slug=slug)
 if test == 0:
return True
else:
for user, movie in check:
if user == request.user.id and movie == watch.id:
return False
else:
return True
def like_view(request, slug):
like = Review.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('review_id'))
 like.likes.add(request.user)
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('movies:detail', args=[slug]))
```

movies_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<img src="{{ articles.image.url }}" width="200px" height="300" style="display: inline-block;" >
<div id="movie_plot">
<h2>{{articles.title}}</h2>
  <p>{{articles.plot}}</p>
{{articles.category}}
  <p>{{articles.cast}}</p>


</div>
{% if isReviewAllowed == True %}
<div class="isReviewAllowed">
        <div class="nav_button"><a class="new_movie" href="{% url 'movies:review' slug=articles.slug %}">Create Review</a></div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% for review in all_reviews %}
{% if review.Review == movie.title  %}
<div class="all_reviews">
<div class="review">
<p><span style="font-weight: normal;">Reviewed by: </span> {{review.user}} </p>
            <p><span style="font-weight: normal;">Description: </span>{{review.text}}</p>
<form style="text-align: center;" action="{% url 'movies:like' slug=articles.slug %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<button style="color: white; background: #104e89;" type="submit", name="review_id", value="{{ review.id }}", class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Like</button> {{review.count_likes}}
</form>
</div>
{% elif review.movie.title == movie.title %}

<div class="review">
<p><span style="font-weight: normal;">Reviewed by: </span> {{review.user}} </p>
        <p><span style="font-weight: normal;">Description: </span>{{review.text}}</p>
</div>

</div>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

so the problem is when i create review with (for example:nir_user make review for batman movie) the review appears in all the movies and not in the specific movie
tell me please if you want me to show you more code.
i attached my views and models files so you can guys see more details about my problem.

Comment: Please provide the models...

Comment: Provide the views too

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem also in my models(the site won't let me attached it
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_comment')

    def count_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.movie.title} 'User:' {self.user}"

Comment: Plz show views. py file

Comment: @BiswajitPaloi

 attached the views and models

Comment: @gpavlov see the comment above

Comment: Where does movie.title come from? Arent you comparing the whole Review object with a title? In this line "review.Review == movie.title"

Comment: @Darjusch
it's in the models, i add it in the first comment above.

Comment: I suspect you save the Review correctly, but then on the movie page where you have the template variable "all_reviews", you forget to filter on that move only. So you really do show all reviews.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich
where do i need to filter ?